# Is the classical Gaussian linear model with unknown σ a generalized linear model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear-model

In Bickle and Doksum's *Mathematical Statistics Vol I*, *Section 6.5 Generalized Linear Models* on p412 says that the linear model with known variance is a special case of a generalized linear model with a canonical link.

> The IV's $Y_i$'s are independent Gaussian with known variance 1 and means $\mu_i = \sum_{j=1}^p Z_{ij} \beta_j$
> The model is GLM with canonical $g(\mu) = \mu$, the identity.

In Section 6.1.1, the Classical Gaussian Linear Model is

$$Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^p Z_{ij} \beta_j + \epsilon_i, $$

for $i=1,...,n$, where $\epsilon_i$'s are iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Is the classical Gaussian linear model with unknown $\sigma$ a generalized linear model? My guess is no, by the definition of generalized linear model on p412, because $Y_i$'s don't serve as statistics in the density function of $Y_i$ written as a distribution in a 2-parameter ($\mu, \sigma$) exponential family on p55. $T(Y)$ is $[Y, Y^2]$ according to p55, not $Y$ as required in (6.5.1) on p412. (I rectangle the parts that I referred to in the following screenshots.)

If you change response variables by letting $W=[Y,Y^2]$, then $W$ satisfies (6.5.1), but $E(W | Z)$ is not $Z*\beta$ any more.

p55:

[image]

p412:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  When $\sigma$ us unknown (which is nigh always), you can still write the normal density in the form of 6.5.1, can you not?  Could you demonstrate the disagreement you claim?

Comment: T(y) is [y, y^2], not y as required in (6.5.1)

Comment: If you change response variables by letting $W=[Y,Y^2]$, then $W$ satisfies (6.5.1), but $E(W | Z)$ is not $Z*\beta$ any more.

Comment: The discussion on p.412 pertains only to "the generalized linear model with dispersion depending only on the mean"; read on to p.416 to learn how this can be extended by introducing an unknown dispersion parameter (the Gaussian model with unknown variance is cited as an example).